# Вывод простых чисел JavaScript

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, простые-числа

Условие:
Напишите код, который выводит все простые числа из интервала от 2 до n.
Для n = 10 результат должен быть 2,3,5,7.

```js
let n = 20;
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  for (let j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
    if ((i % j == 0) && (j != i)) {
      break;
    } else {
      console.log(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

В этом решении выводит 2 3 5 7 9
Не могу понять, почему сюда попадает число 9. Подскажите, кто знает
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Да у вас туда вообще все нечетные числа попадут т.к. `i % 2 == 0` не выполнится для них, будет вывод и `break` во второй ветке. Вообще у вас алгоритм неправильный т.к. сразу же выполняется `break` вместо проверок всех чисел на делитель.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо, нашел решение через метку и continue

Comment: P.s. можно было в цикле записать `j < i` и дополнительно не проверять на `j != i`

Answer (score 1):

Вы совершенно зря увлекаетесь оператором break. Помимо очевидной ненужности в таком  простом коде вы получаете совершенно не читаемый и плохо отлаживаемый код

алгоритм прост:

1) заведем flag=1 - число простое

2) переберем все делители числа от 2 до i/2
   если нашли делитель, то flag=0 (составное) и прекратили перебор делителей

3) если flag=1 то число выводим

```
let n = 20;
for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  let flag=1;
  for (let j = 2; (j <= i/2)&&(flag==1); j=j+1) {
     if (i%j==0) {
         flag=0}
    }
  }
 if (flag==1) {console.log(i);}
}
```

Comment: А что изменится, если написать просто `if( flag )` ?)

Comment: Ничего. Поэтому надо писать flag==1

Answer (score 1):

Не надо проверять до `i/2`, как вам предложили - это слишком долго. До квадратного корня хватит!

```js
let n = 20;

for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    let flag = 1;
    if (i > 2 && i % 2 != 0)
    {
        for (let j = 3; j*j <= i ; j=j+2)
        {
            if (i%j==0)
            {
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (i != 2) flag = 0;
    if (flag==1) {console.log(i);}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function isSimple (n) {
    if (n === 1 || n === 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        for(let i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if(n % i === 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    let n = 10;

    nextPrime:
    for (let i = 2; i <= n; i++) { 
      for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) { 
        if (i % j == 0) continue nextPrime; 
      }

      console.log( i ); 
    }
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, оставте пояснение к вашему решению.

Comment: Плохо. Очень плохо.

Answer (score 0):

```
const n = 100;
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  for (let j = 2; j <= i; j++) {
    if (i % j === 0 && j < i) {
      break;
    } else if (j === i) {
      console.log(i);
    }
  }
}
```

без всякой дичи с флагами и решетом. Исключаются все целочисленные делители  меньше самого итерируемого числа, если таких нет и делитель только само число выводит его в консоль.
Я не силён в математике и новичок в программировании, если будут замечания напишите пжл.